# Why is PHP template not retrieving correct data from mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have three pages:

1. index.php
2. form.php
3. posting.php

It's basically a jobs posting site, where users submit data via the form (form.php), that form data gets put in the database, then I pull that data out into a table on the home page (index.php). Then, if you click on one of the rows in the table, you get taken to the job posting itself (posting.php). It's a lot like a message board. You can see the live version here: You can see the live version at http://onepotcooking.com/students/mattsellers/final_project/final_project.php.

So the problem I'm having is that the job title links in the table are not leading to their corresponding job postings. Every single job title link in the table leads to the same row in the database...that is, the row with id = 1. You'll see that if you click on a job title, the URLs are dynamic...but it just seems that it's not pulling the correct data. I had it working the other day, but for some reason it's not anymore...it's a bummer.

The code I have around the job title links is:

```
<div class='job_title'>
    <span class='job_title_style'>
        <a href="posting.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['job_title'];
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Shouldn't that do it? Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Matt

Comment: The links appear to be working correctly--there's a different id for each of them--I think we need to see your code on the receiving end (your php file).

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for responding. Do you mean the code for the posting.php page?

Comment: You're welcome--I mean the code that grabs the id out of the query string and asks the database for something back :-)

Comment: Hmm, what might that look like? (Sorry if that's a dumb question...I'm pretty new at this). I know that I'm connecting to the database properly...for some reason the posting.php isn't templatized correctly. Every job listing in the table leads to the same entry.

Answer (score 0):

Matt, just thinking. As far as I understood, the link to the offer is put in MySQL also while form is submitted, so you may define the ID part of the link as variable there.

If you do not have a column for the URL in MySQL table, and no query is runing on index.php, just posting the code `echo $row['id']` will not give you the id of the offer.